# low search pagination does not working with structure

Tags: search, structure, low-search, pagination

Low Search pagination does not working with structure. Its only displays first page of pagination. I have also used paginate_base with low search results but issue as it is.

I think issue is low search query which display in url as encrypted.

FYI:

EE: 2.7.2

Low Search: 2.4.2

```
 {exp:low_search:results query="{freebie_5}" paginate="bottom" paginate_base="/{freebie_1}/{freebie_2}/{freebie_3}/{freebie_4}/{freebie_5}/paginate" loose_ends="both" limit="15" status="not closed" disable="member_data|category_fields"}
        <section class="year-block">
            {date_heading display="monthly"}<p class="year-title">{week_date format=" %F, %Y "}</p>{/date_heading}

            <div class="listing {switch='odd|even'}{if press_audio_file !=''} audio-icon{/if} cf">
                <div class="date"><span>{entry_date format="%d"}</span>{entry_date format="%M %Y"}</div>
                <div class="link">
                    <a href="{page_uri}">{title}</a>

                    <div class="postmetadata cf">
                        <p class="release">Release Ref #: <span>{press_number}</span></p>
                        <p class="posted">Posted by: <span>{author}</span></p>
                        <p class="viewed">Viewed: <span>{view_count_one} times</span></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        {paginate}
          {pagination_links}
              <div class="paging cf">
                <span class="page-name">Page({current_page}):</span>
                  {first_page}
                          <a href="{pagination_url}" class="first">First</a>
                  {/first_page}

                  {previous_page}
                          <a href="{pagination_url}" class="prev">Prev</a>
                  {/previous_page}
                  <div class="pages">
                  {page}
                          <a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-{pagination_page_number} {if current_page}current{/if}">{pagination_page_number}</a>
                  {/page}
                  </div>
                  {next_page}
                          <a href="{pagination_url}" class="next">Next</a>
                  {/next_page}

                  {last_page}
                          <a href="{pagination_url}" class="last">Last</a>
                  {/last_page}
              </div>
          {/pagination_links}
        {/paginate}
        {if low_search_no_results}
            <p>
              Sorry, your query did not return any results.
              Check your spelling or try a different search term.
            </p>
        {/if}
    {/exp:low_search:results}
```

Please let me know if you have any solution.

Thanks.

Comment: It's more likely that Structure's the culprit rather than Low Search. [See this thread, for example](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/19980/172). Try paginating a native channel:entries tag and see if the problem persists. If it does not (so only occurs with a Low Search Results tag), post your Low Search Results code here, and your EE, LS and PHP versions.

Comment: @Low I have posted low search result code.

Comment: So, have you tried recreating the issue with the native channel:entries tag?