# Low search pagination not working

Tags: pagination, low-search, low

We have the following on our results page:

```
{layout="site/.html-layout"}

{exp:low_search:results
query="{segment_2}"
require_query="yes"      
limit="20"
paginate="bottom"
status="not closed"
disable="member_data|category_fields"
}

{if count == 1}
<header class="page-header">
    <h1>
        {if get:collection}
            {if get:collection == "companies"}<a href="{path='companies'}">Company Directory</a> / Company {/if}
            {if get:collection == "dictionary"}<a href="{path='dictionary'}">Dictionary</a> / {/if}
        {/if}
        Search Results {if low_search_keywords} for <mark>&ldquo;{low_search_keywords}&rdquo;</mark>{/if} ({if absolute_results != 0}{absolute_results}{if:else}No{/if} result{if absolute_results != 1}s{/if})
    </h1>
</header>

<div class="row">
    <section class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-1 entries_list" style="margin-top: 30px; margin-bottom: 30px;">
        <div class="entries_list">
{/if}

{sn_results_entry_summary}

{if count == total_results}
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
{/if}

{paginate}
{pagination_links}
    <ul class="pagination">
      {first_page}
        <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-first">&laquo;</a></li>
      {/first_page}
      {previous_page}
        <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-previous">&lsaquo;</a></li>
      {/previous_page}
      {page}
        <li{if current_page} class="active"{/if}><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-{pagination_page_number}">{pagination_page_number}</a></li>
      {/page}
      {next_page}
        <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-next">&rsaquo;</a></li>
      {/next_page}
      {last_page}
        <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-last">&raquo;</a></li>
      {/last_page}
      </ul><!-- / .pagination -->
  {/pagination_links}
{/paginate}

{if low_search_no_results}
<header class="page-header">
    <h1>Search Results {if low_search_keywords} for &ldquo;<mark>  {low_search_keywords}</mark>&rdquo;{/if} (No results)</h1>
</header>
<div class="bg-warning" style="padding: 20px 20px 10px 20px; ">
    <p>Sorry, there are currently no search results{if low_search_keywords} for &ldquo;<mark>{low_search_keywords}</mark>&rdquo;{/if}.</p>
</div>
{/if}<!-- low_search_no_results -->

{/exp:low_search:results}
```

This works fine on the first page, and we get the correct results, with an example URL of :

http://example.com/search/results/?collection=articles|case-studies|guides|products|videos|white-papers|dictionary|companies&keywords=test

When we click a pagination link, we get this URL :

http://example.comsearch/results/P20

Which returns no results.

Oddly on another site, with 90% the same code and no differences in results tags it works as we would expect.

We are running ExpressionEngine v2.8.1 - Build Date: 20140314 and LOW Search 3.1.5

**--- EDIT ---**

We've also tried revising the code so that:

The pagination href changes to: {pagination_url}{current_query_string}

Then a url such as http://example.com/search/results?collection=case-studies|guides|&keywords=test

becomes this when a pagination link clicked: http://example.com//search/results/P2collection=case-studies%7Cguides%7C&keywords=test

Which again fails.

Comment: {pagination_url}?{current_query_string} fixed it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try upgrading Low Search to the latest version. [Version 3.1.6](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/changelog#v3.1.6) has this bugfix:

> Fixed a bug where a page URL could be falsely rewritten to maintain the query string

...which should probably fix the issue.

If it does not, try changing the hrefs of the pagination links to:

```
href="{pagination_url}?{current_query_string}"
```

Comment: We just upgraded to 3.3.0 and it does the same.

Comment: How about changing the hrefs from `href="{pagination_url}"` to `href="{pagination_url}{current_query_string}"`?

Comment: Will try that. FYI we also checked this post http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/20033/low-search-pagination-does-not-working-with-structure pagination works fine in the template using normal entries loop.

Comment: It's probably the way LS tries to rewrite the pagination URLs to include the query string. When it fails to do it correctly automatically (which seems the case here), using {current_query_string} should help.

Comment: I've changed the href to: {pagination_url}{current_query_string} then a url such as http://example.com/search/results?collection=case-studies|guides|&keywords=test becomes this when a pagination link clicked: http://example.com//search/results/P2collection=case-studies%7Cguides%7C&keywords=test

Comment: Oh, try `href="{pagination_url}?{current_query_string}"` then.

Comment: {pagination_url}{current_query_string} WORKS! Thanks Low :)

Comment: Changed the answer to include that.

Comment: `href="{pagination_url}?{current_query_string}"` helps me..